# How to implement automatic CLAHE in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, histogram

So I found a paper that deals about improving CLAHE (http://www.iaeme.com/MasterAdmin/UploadFolder/MODIFIED%20CLAHE%20AN%20ADAPTIVE%20ALGORITHM%20FOR%20CONTRAST%20ENHANCEMENT%20OF%20AERIAL%20%20MEDICAL%20AND%20UNDERWATER%20%20IMAGES/MODIFIED%20CLAHE%20AN%20ADAPTIVE%20ALGORITHM%20FOR%20CONTRAST%20ENHANCEMENT%20OF%20AERIAL%20%20MEDICAL%20AND%20UNDERWATER%20%20IMAGES.pdf).

The thing with CLAHE is that it requires 2 input hyperparameters called clip limit (CL) and tilegrid size (N). The paper suggests that the selection can automatically be done by following this algorithm:

[image]

I didn't have much problem coding up to item 4. My problem starts with item 5.3 since as a newbie, I do not understand what is meant by the binary search elaborated. I hope someone can help me.

My code so far:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import skimage.measure  
filename = 'xray.png'
img = cv2.imread(filename)

def getmax_subentropy(s):
    subentropies = []
    n = int(img.shape[0]/s)
    subimgs = [img[x:x+n,y:y+n] for x in range(0,img.shape[0],n) for y in range(0,img.shape[1],n)]
    for i in range(0,s**2):
        subentropies.append(skimage.measure.shannon_entropy(subimgs[i]))
    return(max(subentropies))

entropies = []
for i in range(2,13):
    entropies.append(getmax_subentropy(i))
ind = np.argmax(entropies)
print(ind+2) #====> THIS WILL OUTPUT THE VALUE OF N
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm - you need to develop some sort of binary search here. For that purpose, your data needs to be sorted.

Comment: It is already implemented. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/db6/classcv_1_1CLAHE.html

Comment: @fmw42 sorry for such a newbie question. But I don't get it. Does it mean that  
retval = cv.CLAHE.getClipLimit( ), gives me the cliplimit?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know as I have not used CLAHE before.